# 'Time shift' defaults to previous year - in legacy Metric lens

Tags: kibana, visualization, elastic-stack

I´ve created a Legacy Metric lens that should display the Trend (in percent CO2) compared to a baseyear of 2019. But it always defaults to display the trend compared to previous year.

I´ve created a small [video](https://carboncompute-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/p/andreas_schennings/EU8kW9mcYy9OiUfyf1Qlu4YBM97o1ECfeosTC_HvYjdSVQ?e=p6icnP) here about the error.

This is my code:

`(sum(co2tonnes) - sum(co2tonnes, shift='startAt(2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z)')) / (sum(co2tonnes, shift='startAt(2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z)'))`

It calculates the difference of a sum of co2 compared to 2019 sum, and then it presents it as a percentage.

When I edit the lens and changes the global time, it works perfectly and shows the correct numbers compared to 2019:
2020 -69%
2021 -89%
2022 -98%

But when the lens is saved to the dashboard, it instead shows the numbers compared to prevoius year instead which is wrong:
2020 - 69%
2021 -64%
2022 -78%

Ive compared using the shift='1y' instead, and that works as expected. It is when I try compare with a specific year of 2019 that everything breaks.

This seems to be a bug. Anyone knows what to do?